# jQuery - Get the index of selected check box

Tags: jquery

jQuery 1.7.1 - I have a check box column and would like to get the index of selected boxes as an array or iterate through each checkbox - check whether its selected or not, if selected get the index.

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="it" name="it"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="it" name="it"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not valid to have multiple `input`s in the same form with the same name, except in the case of radio buttons which are essentially a spread-out form of `select`s.

Comment: @Kolink - that is _not_ true. Not only is it valid, it is standard practice for tabular data, i.e., when entering multiple line items. (When submitted, each repeated parameter is usually handled as an array in server-side code.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [`.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) jQuery will pass the index as an argument to the callback function you supply. (You'll probably see a lot of code around that uses `.each()` without parameters on the callback, but that's just because you often don't need to know the index - but it's there for when you do.) Also when calling your function jQuery sets `this` to the current element:

```
$(".it").each(function(i) {
   if (this.checked) {
       alert("Checkbox at index " + i + " is checked.");
   }
});
```

Noting that the index is zero-based, and in case it's not obvious it is the index within the set of elements that matched the selector you supplied (not within all elements in the document).

Note also that above I'm selecting elements by class, but you could select by the name attribute:

```
$('input[name="it"]')
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @nnnnnn. Also, how to retrieve a specific value from an array of hidden input type using index like ' $(".pr")[i].val() '. Do you want me to raise a separate question for this?

Comment: `$(".pr")[i].value` - If you know the index you can use array-style access with the jQuery object but it returns the actual DOM element so you can't use jQuery methods like `.val()` on the result but can get the value by using the standard html input element `value` property.

Comment: Thanks again @nnnnnn. I was breaking my head over this for some time.

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = 0;
$('.it').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert("Box is checked at index=" + index);
    }
    index++;
});
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/bvUND/

Comment: It works. Thanks. Does jQuery provide a way to get the index instead of declaring a variable 'index'? Something like 'this.index'.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old posting but I came across it while helping out elsewhere, just wanted to add some code regarding your request of not having an explicit index var for keeping track of the index. The value returned from index() is zero-based.

```
var myCheckboxes = $("input[type=checkbox].it");

myCheckboxes.each(function(){
    alert(myCheckboxes.index(this));
    // do whatever you need with the index of the checkbox
}
```

More on .index() can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/index/