# How to get the index of the checkbox list

Tags: jquery

I need to loop through the checkbox list. I searched the web and found some code. However I still have a problem - the `alert` only shows the first time and the index is `0`. I referenced this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122909/jquery-get-the-index-of-selected-check-box#).

```
<tr>
  <td>Language:</td>
  <td>
    <asp:checkboxlist runat="server" ID="chk" cssClass="chkClass"></asp:checkboxlist>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hd" runat="server" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
function setcheckbox() {
  $('.chkClass').each(function (i, obj) {
    alert(i);
    if (i == 2) {
      this.prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<asp:CheckBoxList cssClass="myClass">` renders as `<ul class="myClass">`. Therefore, you're not looping through the items, you're looping through the (single) `<ul>`.

Try adding `input[type=checkbox]` to your selector, specifying that you're looking for the checkboxes *within* the `<ul>`.

```
function setcheckbox() {
  $('.chkClass input[type=checkbox]').each(function (i, obj) {
    alert(i);
    if (i == 2) {
      this.prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
}
```